# System of PDEs involving two distinct functions

Tags: differential-equations

Given functions $f, g: \mathbf{R}^2 \longrightarrow \mathbf{R}$, how would one go about solving the system

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} &= -g(x, y)\\
\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial y} &= f(x, y)
\end{align*}

for $f$ and $g$?

Comment: Apologies for the unrendered LaTeX. I'm getting a weird formatting error.

Comment: Hi. This looks like a question for MathematicS SE, not MathematicA SE.

Comment: As asked by @user293787 , is this a question about software _Mathematica_? If not, you should ask it in https://math.stackexchange.com/ . If it's a _Mathematica_ question, what have you tried? Do you need a symbolic or numeric solution? Do you need a general solution or particular solution? If you need a general solution, is the solution shown by Nasser in answer below desired? If you need particular solution, what's the corresponding initial/boundary condition? Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

I tried V 13.1 and it can't solved it. May be next version will.  But there is a solution using Maple 2022.1

```
Clear["Global`*"]
pde1 = D[f[x, y], x] + D[f[x, y], y] == -g[x, y]
pde2 = D[g[x, y], x] + D[g[x, y], y] == f[x, y]
DSolve[{pde1, pde2}, {f[x, y], g[x, y]}, {x, y}]
```

Returns unevaluated. Using Maple:

```
restart;
pde1 := diff(f(x,y),x) + diff(f(x,y),y)  = -g(x,y);
pde2 := diff(g(x,y),x) + diff(g(x,y),y)  =  f(x,y);
pdsolve([pde1,pde2],[f(x,y),g(x,y)])
```

Gives

```
{f(x, y) = -exp(-I*x)*_F1(y - x)*I + exp(x*I)*_F2(y - x)*I, g(x, y) = exp(-I*x)*_F1(y - x) + exp(x*I)*_F2(y - x)}
```

Which in Mathematica notation is

```
{f[x, y] -> -Exp[-I*x]*F1[y - x]*I + Exp[x*I]*F2[y - x]*I, 
 g[x, y] -> Exp[-I*x]*F1[y - x] + Exp[x*I]*F2[y - x]}
```

$$
\left\{f(x,y)\to i e^{i x} \text{F2}(y-x)-i e^{-i x} \text{F1}(y-x),g(x,y)\to e^{-i x} \text{F1}(y-x)+e^{i x} \text{F2}(y-x)\right\}
$$

Where in the above $F1$ and $F2$ are arbitrary functions.